# Loop without first statement (C to visual basic)

Tags: c, vb.net, loops, for-loop, vb6

I have the next code in C:

```
for (i = 0; i < Nk; ++i)
    {
        // some actions using i as an index
    }
for (; (i < (Nb * (Nr + 1))); ++i)
    {
        // another actions. Here i starts from value in previous loop
    }
```

Now I try to convert it to Visual Basic (in VB 6.0 really...)
First part is easy:

```
For i = 0 To Nk - 1                                                             
    ' my actions
Next
```

But second loop confuse me a bit.
Is there some way to make this loop or I just need to put some constant value here?

Comment: I suppose `For i = i To (Nb * (Nr + 1))-1` may be worth a shot. Been a long time since I hit up VB, so ymmv.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think this way too! Now I'm checking this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution:

```
 For i = i To (Nb * (Nr + 1)) - 1
     ' my actions
 Next
```

Thanks to [@WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) - he give the same solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

Just to have more options, Another example could be:

```
dim lst = Enumerable.Range(0, (Nb * (Nr + 1)) - 1)
```

And then use LINQ Expressions, for example (just made up):

```
lst.Select(function(x) 
             if x mod 2 = 0 then
                return x * 2
             else 
                return x
             end if
            end function)
```

Comment: I read about Enumeration and find it useful. So I can use Enumerable variable instead of loop using Select. But I can't understand statement in brackets. Can you clarify it a bit for me?

I get error using `function(i)` because I use `i` in previous loop.
And second question: for my second loop I have to use `Enumerable.Range(i, (Nb * (Nr + 1)) - 1)`, isn't it?

Comment: I have elaborated a made up example, hope this clarifies your question. Also, yes, if the variable in the lambda is already used in your code, you will have to change it. Finally, considering the variables stated in your question, yes, your second loop will look like in your comment.

Comment: Now I get it! Thank you for clarification!

Comment: Be aware this nice code is VB.Net and won't compile in VB6. Mikhail_Sam, I would advise you to tag your questions with `vb6` only, not `vb.net`. You say in your question that you are

Comment: @MarkJ oh thank you! It is very important! I set `vb.net` too just because I want to find any solution and hope that I can translate some `vb.net` code to `vb6` manually.

Comment: I strongly recommend tagging with VB6 only. Otherwise you will get beautiful answers like this one, that you just cannot translate to VB6.